# Compute the Variance of $[min(X^2,\eta_0) - min(X^2,\eta_1)]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose  $$X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$ There is another function $w$ given as $$W=min(X^2,\eta_0)-min(X^2,\eta_1)$$ where $\eta_0$ and $\eta_1$ are constant and $\eta_1> \eta_0$.

> Now I want to ask what will be 
>   $var(W)$=??

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$W = \begin{cases}
\eta_0 - \eta_1 & \text{if } X^2 > \eta_1 \\
\eta_0 - X^2 & \text{if }  \eta_1 \ge X^2 > \eta_0 \\
0 & \text{if }  \eta_0 \ge X^2
\end{cases}$$

Calculating the first two moments of $W$ now comes down to just some tedious but simple calculations of integrals containing the Gaussian density (You will presumably need partial integration). The solution will probably not be an elementary function, but contain the CDF $\Phi$ of the (standard) normal distribution.

Note that you can assume $\sigma^2 = 1$, since 
$$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}W = \min\left(\left(\frac{X}{\sigma}\right)^2, \frac{\eta_0}{\sigma^2}\right) - \min\left(\left(\frac{X}{\sigma}\right)^2, \frac{\eta_1}{\sigma^2}\right)$$

and $\frac{X}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would be glad if you can elaborate because Canardini answer doesn't seems to me fit. There are small but many mistakes.

Comment: Write $W = (\eta_0 - \eta_1) I\{X^2 > \eta_1\} + (\eta_0 - X^2) I\{\eta_1 \ge X^2 > \eta_0\}$ and then calcualte $E[W]$ and $E[W^2]$. This is just some tedious work that you should be able to do on your own.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am confused about integral limits because of square term. If you can just write the beginning of all integral with corresponding limits required then I will solve rest by myself. I just want the initial steps.

Comment: Just use the linearity of the expectation, there is no complicated trick involved. Then you should also see what the corresponding limits are.

Answer (score 1):

$E(W)=E(W1_{X^2<\eta_0})+E(W1_{\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1})+E(W1_{\eta_1\leq X^2})$

$=E((X^2-X^2)1_{X^2<\eta_0})+E((\eta_0-X^2)1_{\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1})+E((\eta_0-\eta_1)1_{X^2\geq\eta_1})$

$=E((\eta_0-X^2)1_{\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1})+(\eta_0-\eta_1)P({ X^2\geq\eta_1})$

$=(\eta_0-\eta_1)P({ |X|\geq\sqrt{\eta_1}})+\eta_0P(\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1)-E(X^21_{\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1})$

$P({ |X|\geq\sqrt{\eta_1}})=P({ X\geq\sqrt{\eta_1}})+P({ X\leq-\sqrt{\eta_1}})$

$E(W^2)=E(W^21_{X^2<\eta_0})+E(W^21_{\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1})+E(W^21_{\eta_1\leq X^2})$

$=E((\eta_0-X^2)^21_{\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1})+(\eta_0-\eta_1)^2P({ X^2\geq\eta_1})$

$=E((\eta_0^2-2\eta_0X^2+X^4)1_{\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1})+(\eta_0-\eta_1)^2P({ |X|\geq\sqrt{\eta_1}})$

All it remains to do is to know the entities of the following form :

$$P({a\leq X<b})$$

$$E(X^21_{a\leq X^2<b})$$

$$E(X^41_{a\leq X^2<b})$$

with $0<a<b$

Moreover, $1_{a\leq X^2<b}=1_{\sqrt{a}\leq X<\sqrt{b}}+1_{-\sqrt{b}\leq X<-\sqrt{a}}$

We know that

$$P({a\leq X<b})=\Phi(\frac{b}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{a}{\sigma})$$, with $\Phi$ the cdf of a centered normally distributed variable.

The following can be calculated by integrating by parts. 
$$E(X^21_{a\leq X<b})=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\frac{a}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b}{\sigma}}{x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx}$$

and
$$E(X^41_{a\leq X<b})=\frac{\sigma^4}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\frac{a}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b}{\sigma}}{x^4e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx}$$

Comment: Don't you think there is a mistake in last term of second line. It should be $1_{\eta_1<X^2}$ instead of $1_{\eta_0 \leq X^2<\eta_1}$

Comment: And same in sixth line as well. Can you please clarify.

Comment: Yes big typo, I fixed it . Thanks

Comment: It would be good if you can mention how to calculate $P({ |X|\geq\sqrt{\eta_1}})$

Comment: Look at the 5th line .You just use the cdf of X. In that case , you have$$1-\Phi(\sqrt{\eta_1})+\Phi(-\sqrt{\eta_1})$$

Comment: Thanks. Will it also be same for $$P({ |X|\leq\sqrt{\eta_1}})=P({ X\geq\sqrt{\eta_1}})+P({ X\leq-\sqrt{\eta_1}})$$

Comment: No, it will be 
$$P({ |X|\leq\sqrt{\eta_1}})=P({ X\leq\sqrt{\eta_1}})-P({ X\leq-\sqrt{\eta_1}})$$

Comment: Hey, and what about $$P(\sqrt{\eta_0}\leq |X|<\sqrt{\eta_1})=??$$. I think there will be four possibilities of this as well. What do you say??

Comment: Two possibilities exactly, $P(\sqrt{\eta_0}\leq X<\sqrt{\eta_1})$ and $P(-\sqrt{\eta_1}\leq X<-\sqrt{\eta_0})$
$$P(\eta_0\leq X^2<\eta_1)=P(\sqrt{\eta_0}\leq X<\sqrt{\eta_1})+P(-\sqrt{\eta_1}\leq X<-\sqrt{\eta_0})$$

Comment: Thanks. I want to know, do the limits of integral will also be affected by it or it will be same as you shown.

Comment: Hi, I want to to know why did you take $X$ as unit variance in last two integral which ??....If you changed it to unit variance then it would be better if you take another variable and also there is mistake in the power of $\sigma$ of both integral.

Comment: Yeah the power was a typo, it is fixed. I did not assume that X as a unit variance, I am just saying that X has the same distribution as $\sigma Y$ where Y as a unit variance.

Comment: Using integration by parts, one can express the partial moments in terms of $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ the standard gaussian CDF and PDF. Assuming that $X$ is standard normal and that $0<u<v$ and using $x\varphi(x)=-\varphi'(x)$, one gets $$E(X^2;u^2<X^2<v^2)=2\int_u^vx^2\varphi(x)dx=\left.-2x\varphi(x)\right|_u^v+2\int_u^v\varphi(x)dx$$ hence $$E(X^2;u^2<X^2<v^2)=2u\varphi(u)-2v\varphi(v)+2\Phi(v)-2\Phi(u)$$ and similarly for $$E(X^4;u^2<X^2<v^2)=2\int_u^vx^4\varphi(x)dx=\left.-2x^3\varphi(x)\right|_u^v+6\int_u^vx^2\varphi(x)dx=\cdots$$

Comment: @Did Thanks. You gave me another way of solving the integral. But I wonder you didn't included the mod. By mod I mean $$u^2<X^2<v^2 = u<|X|<y$$. So it does break into two $u<X<v$ & $-u<X<-v$. I think in integral we have to consider both limits.

Comment: Because both integrals contribute equally, hence the factor 2 in my previous comment.

Comment: @Canardini Hey what about the limits of Integral. Don't you think last two integral should be like this  $$E(X^21_{a\leq |X|<b})=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{-\frac{b}{\sigma}}^{-\frac{a}{\sigma}}{x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx}+\int_{\frac{a}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b}{\sigma}}{x^2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx}\right)$$

 and
$$E(X^41_{a\leq |X|<b})=\frac{\sigma^4}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{-\frac{b}{\sigma}}^{-\frac{a}{\sigma}}{x^4e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx}+\int_{\frac{a}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b}{\sigma}}{x^4e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx}\right)$$

Comment: @Did Thanks.Yes you are correct.

Comment: One more thing that I notice that you didn't mentioned

$$E(X^21_{a\leq X<b})= \frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\frac{a}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b}{\sigma}}{x^2f(x \mid a \leq x <b)dx}$$

Now
$$E(X^21_{a\leq X<b})=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\frac{a}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b}{\sigma}}{x^2\frac{f(x)}{\mathbb{P}( a \leq x <b)}dx}$$

Hence
$$E(X^21_{a\leq X<b})=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{\Phi(\frac{b}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{a}{\sigma})}\int_{\frac{a}{\sigma}}^{\frac{b}{\sigma}}{x^2f(x)dx}$$